# how to make WP7 app not to go lock mode as the device is set to go lock for every 30 sec?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I mean app should run even in lock mode without going back to lock mode?

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [Idle Detection for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), especially to User Idle Detection Mode section

Comment: ya you r right but i am unable to do from that even if i disabled ApplicationIdleDetectionMode. Here is a code   PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

Comment: UserIdleDetectionMode, not ApplicationIdleDetectionMode (as I understand that you need to prevent phone locking)

Comment: ya its worked ..Thank you  and one more help , can we have a control on brightness of the screen ..? I mean i need to make the screen dim after few seconds and after a tap it should be bright..

Comment: @bharat - the brightness thing is an entirely different question, so ask a new question. stackoverflow is **not** a forum and comments shouldn't be used to emulate one =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx

Comment: ya i did that but i need to stop all activities doing by the system in Obscured  method and i am unable to that . Can u help me in that please..?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding following code in App.xaml.cs file public App() constructor

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

This statement `Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;` 
of disabling 'UserIdleDetectionMode' property makes operating system to not to go into idle mode(low power usage state).

This is required in addition 'ApplicationIdleDetectionMode' property disabling, if your application needs to continue running even when the user is not physically interacting with the screen or hardware buttons.

Comment: Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;  This statment works fine for application runnin continues .Thank you santosh